# tar.gz file encrypted with truecrypt, how to decode it?

Tags: truecrypt, decryption

I have installed truecrypt and try it with tar.gz file, where I had some important data.  
Now when I mount this file I just see empty folder, 
and was not able to find some solution, how to decode the file to be extractable?

Is it even possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you made a truecrypt file,and compress that file to tar.gz format.Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, when I was selecting file in truecrypt for encryption I choosed tar.gz file with some data and they now seems lost.

Comment: you already encrypted tar.gz file with truecrypt,but when you decrypt nothing was found.

Comment: I dont know how to decrypt it, for what I have found, some suggests that for encryption i should just copy files from mounted drive, but obviously I can't do that, since it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose a file that already exists as your `Truecrypt` container, that file is **overwritten**. You create a truecrypt volume and place the files inside that volume, you do not encrypt a file such as a `tar.gz` like you might do with `openssl`.

When you create a volume, you should get this warning:

[image]

Unfortunately you have lost your data, although if you manipulated the files concerned on other areas of your drive, you might be able to recover something by using recovery software. Please see this article, which details various approaches:

- [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Thx you saved me time.